# Continue button is not working in prestashop in Registration process after check-out

Tags: web, prestashop, e-commerce

after uploading a COD module in prestashop, my website is not proceeding to continue to address after filling the form of personal information.

[Here in image you can see this continue button is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc85y.png)

Comment: You get an error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to place an order using your COD module, so I guess you have resolved it?

[image: Order using the COD module]